# How can i use different database in django management command

Tags: python, django

I am using django management command in my test like this

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('loadusers')
```

Now I have the database on external server where i want to execute this command not on the database where the django currently is executing the tests.

How can i something like

```
call_command('loadusers', database="external")
```

Comment: I'd imagine you'd have to use a custom management command and then use python db access code, I don't think you need to use django specifics here

Comment: You'd have to add "external" to your database settings.

Comment: You are running a django test suite but while that test suite is running you would like that code to execute a management command on a different database. Did I get that right?

Comment: @e4c5 yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

```
    settings.DATABASES[FIXTURE_DATABASE] = {
                "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
                "NAME": "external",
            }
call_command("loadusers", database=FIXTURE_DATABASE, verbosity=0,
                interactive=False)
```

I think it should work,found this here at Example 14 :  http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/56194/django.core.management.call_command

Comment: thanks i will try that .  didn't knew about that site :)